# Feature Request: Not tag inheritance, but tag suggestions?

Tags: feature-request

There have beens some questions asked before about tag inheritance, and while it would certainly be useful in many situations, there would be some unfortunate side effects.

The example I came across was the following:

```
html -> html version 4
     -> html version 5
```

If you add html, you might not want to automatically inherit html-5.

But, consider the following (very useful) hierarchy:

```
microsoft -> microsoft windows
          -> windows
          -> windows-95
          -> windows-98
          -> windows-2000
          -> windows-xp
          -> windows-vista
          -> windows-7
          -> windows-8 -> windows 8.1
          -> windows-10
          -> microsoft-office -> microsoft-word
                              -> microsoft-excel
                              -> microsoft-powerpoint
                              -> microsoft-outlook -> microsoft-outlook-2010
                                                   -> microsoft-outlook-2013
```

You can add to that list if you like - similarly with `google`, there are things like `google app engine`, `youtube`, `youtube-api`, `google-api`, etc.

While I agree that the tag inheritance would be:

- A lot of work to maintain *well*
- Sometimes a matter of debate (eg: is microsoft a sub-tag of "commercial-software"? rather than "open-source"? or is `microsoft` a "root tag"? both could be logical?
- Would require a feature which allows you to hide all (example) `microsoft` tags, but then *override* this option by putting the *sub-tag* `microsoft-outlook` in your "favorite tags"

And for these reasons, it has been suggested that it would not be a good idea to add tag inheritance, but I feel that it would be useful to have tag suggestions of related tags.

These could either be implemented using a maintained tree structure, as you would have for tag inheritance, *or* could be implemented by analysing data from other users...

Using the second method would remove the "debatable" aspect of whether 1 tag is or is not a sub-tag of any other.

To elaborate: If I edit my favourite tags and add `microsoft-windows`, then StackOverflow's algorithms should go away, find all users with that tag set as a favourite, and then return a list of say 5 (or 10?) "most popular tags" from all the users found with the `microsoft-windows` tag set in their favorites.

My guess would be this algorithm would return:

`windows-7`, `windows-8`, `windows-10`, `windows-xp`, `windows-8.1`, `windows-98`

... for example.

I think this would be a worthwhile feature, because I often set a tag to show or hide questions, and then later find questions appearing which I did not want to appear, because a *related* tag was included, but the tag I specified as "hide" did not. The reverse is sometimes also true. (Eg: Some people tag `windows-8` but not `windows`.)

Comment: You can already do something a bit like that by searching for e.g. `[windows*]`, which is expanded automagically to search all tags starting with the word *"windows"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the info - does this work if I put such a tag in the show / hide tag options?

Comment: You mean favourite/ignore? I've never actually tried that, so I couldn't tell you!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately it doesn't seem to...

Comment: I recall that it does work on favorite tags.

Comment: It does work on favourite tags. Just type it in and click add without selecting a tag.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll try it again - can you over-ride it by specifying a specific tag in the "favourite tags" section? IE: Don't show any windows questions unless they are about windows-8 specifically?

Comment: This sounds like pretty much every shopping site's "people who have bought this product bought these products too" feature. Which always fails. For instance, I bought some relatively high-end AA batteries on Amazon several years ago, and I still get suggestions for camera equipment. Apparently only photographers need good AA batteries. I really don't want to add `[javascript]` and have SO start suggesting `[php]` questions to me...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You have missed the point - only the suggestion for more tags would be suggested to you while editing your tag subscriptions. Perhaps I didn't make that clear?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No I did - see paragraph near bottom beginning with "To elaborate"

Comment: Ah, I missed that, apologies. I'm still not sure I'd use it, but it's a decent enough proposal.

Comment: Having seen these "dropdown menu" ASCII art graphics, I'm really in favour of actual heirarchies now.